# Google cloud dataflow and machine learning

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-ml

What's the best way to run machine learning algorithms on Google Cloud Dataflow? I can imagine that using Mahout would be one option given it's Java based.

The answer is probably no, but is there a way to invoke R or Python (that have strong support for algorithms) based scripts to offload ML execution?

-Girish

Comment: Do you have realtime requirements? If not, you could use/test [the Python SDK for Google Cloud Dataflow (beta)](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python), this will make it even easier to use ML libraries like scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can already implement many algorithms in terms of Dataflow transforms.

A class of algorithms that may not be as easy to implement are iterative algorithms, where the pipeline's execution graph depends on the data itself. Simplifying implementation of iterative algorithms is something that we are interested in, and you can expect future improvements and simplifications in this area.

Invoking Python (or any other) executable shouldn't be hard from a Dataflow pipeline. A ParDo can, for example, shell out and start an arbitrary process. You can use, for example, `--filesToStage` pipeline option to add additional files to the Dataflow worker environment.

Comment: Could you clarify or provide example of what you mean by 'Invoking Python (or any other) executable shouldn't be hard from a Dataflow pipeline'?

Comment: You can write a `DoFn` that shells out to any executable. Then, apply that `DoFn` via `ParDo` to any Dataflow `Pipeline`.

Comment: Do you mean using ProcessBuilder?

Comment: Several ways of doing that -- `ProcessBuilder()` and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` are common ones.

Answer (score 0):

There is also http://quickml.org/ (haven't used personally) and Weka. I remember the docs mention that it's possible to launch a new process from within the job, but AFAIK it's not recommended.